# More efficient Update query (MS SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I'm trying to update multiple columns from TableA below with a corresponding ADDR_IDs from TableB.  This is a snippet, in reality I have 30 Locations in TableA and 30 EXT_IDs in TableB so doing Update statements would take an eternity.  The problem is that any one of the 30 Locations in TableA could exists in any of the 30 EXT_IDs in TableB.

For example, in TableA, ID = 44231, Location A35555 might match up in TableB in EXT_ID_27, so im really hoping someone can suggest a better alternative than 900 update statements...

SQL Fiddle below

TableA

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------+
| ID      | LOC_1     | LOC_1_ADDR_ID                       | LOC_2          | LOC_2_ADDR_ID                       |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------------------|----------------+-------------------------------------|
| 44231   | A35555    | Trying to Populate Should Be Z76543 | B68754         | Trying to Populate should be Z45545 |
| 87563   | A36666    | Trying to Populate Should Be Z83465 | Q23548         | Trying to Populate should be Z89224 |
| 85387   | R14587    | Trying to Populate Should be Z66371 | A35555         | Trying to Populate should be Z93827 |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------|
```

TableB ( EXT_ID is unique per REC_ID but multiple REC_ID's could have the same EXT_ID)

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| REC_ID  | ADDR_ID_1 | EXT_ID_1    | ADDR_ID_2 | EXT_ID_2  | (28 more external ID columns)
+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 44231   | Z76543    | A35555      | Z45545    | B68754    |
| 87563   | Z83465    | A36666      | Z89224    | Q23548    |
| 85387   | Z93827    | A35555      | Z66371    | R14587    |
+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------|-----------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02d5c/5/0

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to update 30 columns in table A with corresponding values from the table B, and each join should occur on a different column (LOC_1 = EXT_ID_1 to update LOC_1_ADDR_ID, LOC_2 = EXT_ID_2 to update LOC_2_ADR_ID, etc) ?

Comment: Sort of, Loc_1 = EXT_ID_1 through EXT_ID_30 (Could be a match in any of the 30 EXT_ID columns) but only one match would exists in those 30 EXT_ID's.  I'm reading through your suggestions thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 30 column "pairs" in table B are in fact repeated data with the same meaning (a location key/address pair), then the design should be only 2 columns with more data. The actual table isn't following this design, but the data you query can.

```
SELECT EXT_ID_1 AS EXT_ID, ADDR_ID_1 AS ADDR_ID FROM TableB UNION ALL
SELECT EXT_ID_2 AS EXT_ID, ADDR_ID_2 AS ADDR_ID FROM TableB UNION ALL
SELECT EXT_ID_3 AS EXT_ID, ADDR_ID_3 AS ADDR_ID FROM TableB UNION ALL
...
SELECT EXT_ID_30 AS EXT_ID, ADDR_ID_30 AS ADDR_ID FROM TableB
```

This gets you two columns of data, which is easier to write a query against. Dump this in a temporary table (or a table variable) and you can go ahead with 30 UPDATE statements, which is better than 900.

Alternatively, you could try this in a single statement :

```
WITH (
  SELECT EXT_ID_1 AS EXT_ID, ADDR_ID_1 AS ADDR_ID FROM TableB UNION ALL
  SELECT EXT_ID_2 AS EXT_ID, ADDR_ID_2 AS ADDR_ID FROM TableB UNION ALL
  SELECT EXT_ID_3 AS EXT_ID, ADDR_ID_3 AS ADDR_ID FROM TableB UNION ALL
  ...
  SELECT EXT_ID_30 AS EXT_ID, ADDR_ID_30 AS ADDR_ID FROM TableB
) AS SimplifiedTableB
UPDATE TableA
SET
  LOC_1_ADDR_ID = COALESCE(TableB1.ADDR_ID, LOC_1_ADDR_ID),
  LOC_2_ADDR_ID = COALESCE(TableB2.ADDR_ID, LOC_2_ADDR_ID),
  LOC_3_ADDR_ID = COALESCE(TableB3.ADDR_ID, LOC_3_ADDR_ID),
  ...
  LOC_30_ADDR_ID = COALESCE(TableB30.ADDR_ID, LOC_30_ADDR_ID)
FROM
  TableA
  LEFT JOIN SimplifiedTableB AS TableB1 ON TableA.LOC1 = TableB1.EXT_ID
  LEFT JOIN SimplifiedTableB AS TableB2 ON TableA.LOC2 = TableB2.EXT_ID
  LEFT JOIN SimplifiedTableB AS TableB3 ON TableA.LOC3 = TableB3.EXT_ID
  ...
  LEFT JOIN SimplifiedTableB AS TableB30 ON TableA.LOC30 = TableB30.EXT_ID
```

I would recommend testing this beforehand, however, both for correctness and performance reasons.

Comment: This is great, I needed to add the REC_ID because EXT_ID is not unique in the table but it is for each REC_ID so this allowed me to determine if an EXT_ID exists for each REC_ID and return the associated ADDR_ID.  TableB only has 90k records and grows slow so even though this produces a table with ~3M records it works just fine for the daily job it's supporting.  Thanks Jonathan!

Answer (score 1):

Noticed this is answered and since I was working on this anyway, here is an alternative ..
Some info received from [Unpivot multi columns](http://pratchev.blogspot.ca/2009/02/unpivoting-multiple-columns.html)

```
select tblB.REC_ID, tblB.ADDR_ID, tblB.EXT_ID
into #tempTableB
from
(
  select REC_ID, ADDR_ID, EXT_ID
  from TableB
  Unpivot
    (
      ADDR_ID for ADDR_IDS in (ADDR_ID_1, ADDR_ID_2)
    ) as UnPvtADDR
  Unpivot
    (
      EXT_ID for EXT_IDS in (EXT_ID_1, EXT_ID_2)

    ) as UnPvtEXT
  where RIGHT(ADDR_IDS, 1) = RIGHT(EXT_IDS, 1)
) tblB

-- [depend on number of records in #tmepTableB]
-- Create Index on #tempTablB.REC_ID to improve performance if required

update tblA
set LOC_1_ADDR_ID = (select ADDR_ID from #tempTableB where REC_ID = tblA.ID and EXT_ID = tblA.LOC_1)
, LOC_2_ADDR_ID = (select ADDR_ID from #tempTableB where REC_ID = tblA.ID and EXT_ID = tblA.LOC_2)
-- .. and the rest of the columns
from TableA tblA
  inner join
  #tempTableB tblB
on tblA.ID = tblB.REC_ID
where tblA.ID = tblB.REC_ID

select * from TableA
```